# How can i sort Rdd[(Int, (val1, val2))] by val2, when only SortByKey is available as option?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I have a `Rdd[(Int, (val1, val2))]` which i want to sort by val2, but the only available option to use is `SortByKey`. 
Is SortBy available only in older `scala` versions? 
Is there another option than collecting it to driver?

In code i do only:

```
val nonslack = slacks.filter(x=> Vlts.contains(x._1))
```

where `Vlts` is `Array[Int]` and `slacks` is `rdd` read from file.

Comment: Can't you use dataframe for this? like `sort` or `orderBy`

Answer (score 0):

There is a sortBy in RDD:

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("one", ("one" -> 1)), ("two", ("two" -> 2)), ("three", ("three" -> 3))))

rdd.sortBy(_._2._2).collect().foreach(println(_))
```

Comment: any idea why there is no such option for me?

Comment: please, edit your question and include the code in it